# R strftime - timezone issue & issue with empty cells in date colume

Tags: r, datetime, strptime

I am working on a shiny app, the dataframe to be loaded into the shiny app have two timestamp columns, `open time` and `close time`, all the rows in  column have timestamps, but in `close time` column have several missing timestamps.

I am trying to convert these timestamps which are in `dd mmm,yyyy hh:mm:ss` format to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format, the code that I am trying to use is

```
df1$OPEN.TIME <- strptime(df1$OPEN.TIME,format ='%d %b,%Y %H:%M:%S')
df1$CLOSED.TIME <- strptime(df1$CLOSED.TIME,format ='%d %b,%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

For the `OPEN.TIME` I am getting an output like this eg. (2016-01-12T14:24:34Z) but the time is different from the actual time on the column, I understand this is because `strptime`is converting to timestamp to system timezone, on the next column CLOSED.TIME with empty, I get an error:

```
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

here is an example dataframe that I am trying to work

```
    df1<-data.table(Quiz = c(1:5),
OPEN.TIME=c("06 Jul,2017 08:00:23", "12 Jan,2016 09:24:34","17 Jan,2016 15:03:24", "15 Feb,2016 09:09:28", "08 Mar,2016 11:29:06"),
CLOSED.TIME=c("08 Mar,2016 11:29:06", "","02 Mar,2016 14:46:19", "13 Apr,2016 16:36:11", ""))
```

Comment: error <character string is not in a standard unambiguous format>

Comment: please help me fix

Comment: Can you edit with a reproducible example (you can use `dput()` for the data frame)?

Comment: I get an output like this with OPEN.TIME `c(23, 34, 24, 28, 6)`